# Icon button from react-native-paper does not work when i run web

Tags: react-native

I´m doing an list with a button on right side, but when i run the app on web, button did not recieve a click.

```
<List.Item
  title={item.animal_id.nome_completo}
  description={`Descrição do ${item.animal_id.tipo}`}
  left={(props) => <List.Image {...props} source={require("../assets/logo.png")} />}
    right={() => (
    <IconButton
      icon="star"
      iconColor={DefaultTheme.colors.primary}
      size={20}
      onPress={() => alert("Pet já favoritado")}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

I try switch IconButton for a button but too don´t recieve a click, I want to alert something on click when I run the app on web by Expo Go